# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role : could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, proxy

```
Exception:

failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.cerner.budgetmanagement.model.Team.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.cerner.budgetmanagement.model.Team["users"])
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening? I learning to use jersey in spring/hibernate environment. My understanding of this lazy initialization was because of session going out scope. Thanks in advance.

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    @GET
    @Path("/name/{teamId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getBudgetPlan(@PathParam("teamId") int teamId) { 

        teamDao = applicationContext.getBean("dao", Dao.class);
        final Team team = teamDao.getModelById(Team.class, teamId);
        Hibernate.initialize(team);
        return Response.status(201).entity(team).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a Lazy collection to load for Team.users.
This is possibly a problem with your TransactionManager.

Create a TransactionManager for your HibernateSession(If not already created) and Annotate your getModelById method with @Transactional.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to initialize a lazy relation. Initializing means that Hibernate tries to execute a `SELECT` statement in order to get the data.

This is problematic because you don't have any `Transaction` around the code which is initializing.

Please refer to my article for detailed understading: http://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/2017/02/27/lazyinitializationexception-demystified/